# Attaching already detached Data and Log files in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 2 directories of detached SQL Server `.mdf`'s and `.ldf`'s respectively, are there any scripts in T-SQL or Powershell that can pick these files up and attach them to a SQL Server without manually inputting every specific file?

Occasionally unattached data and log files would be dumped to these locations so I would ideally like to not update the script every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Attach-all-the-databases-ace9ed34

A few tweaks here and there and it did exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can Schedule a job to execute the following T-sql statements and it will do the job for you.

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE DATABASE [DataBase_Name] ON
( FILENAME = N'C:\Data\DataBase_Name_Data.mdf' ), --<---- Path to your .mdf file------
( FILENAME = N'C:\Data\DataBase_Name_Log.ldf' )   --<---- Path to your .ldf file------
FOR ATTACH
GO
```